# svn:externals analog in GIT

Tags: git, svn

I have two projects and one common directory who use both of projects.
In svn I use svn:externals to make clone of common directory in both projects.
I can change common directory in first project and these changes will appear in second project (after commit+update).
It's like link in both projects to common directory.
Can I do something like this in git?

To have common directory in one repository with projects in single brunch.

Thank you

Comment: I believe what you’re looking for is a submodule. https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt